# Show/hide divs according to multiple data values

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

This has been driving me crazy. Couldn´t get a definitive answer from chatgpt nor reddit.
Maybe stackoverflow has someone who is willing to help me out or give guidance.

**Description:**
When button is activated, the cities in its data must be shown (the divs below). When button is deactivated then the cities in its data must be hidden, BUT, not hidden when there´s another active button with the same city in its data.

It works fine when activating buttons, but fails when deactivating. For example activate "toronto, seattle" and "miami, seattle" and then deactivate "miami, seattle". It hides miami, but also seattle but shouldn´t, since "toronto, seattle" is still active.

*So far i was able to come up with this:*

```js
$('.city-button').click(function() {
    const btns = $('.city-button');
    const cities = $(this).data('cities').split(', ');

    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            $(this).removeClass('active')   
            $('#' + cities[i]).hide()
        }
    }else{
        for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            $(this).addClass('active')  
            $('#' + cities[i]).show()
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.city {display: none;}
.active {background-color: yellow; color: black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="city-button" type="button" data-cities="toronto, seattle">toronto, seattle</button>
<button class="city-button" type="button" data-cities="miami, seattle">miami, seattle</button>
<button class="city-button" type="button" data-cities="atlanta">atlanta</button>

<div id="toronto" class="city">toronto</div>
<div id="seattle" class="city">seattle</div>
<div id="miami" class="city">miami</div>
<div id="atlanta" class="city">atlanta</div>
```

Comment: Think about what your code does when you click an active button. A debugger may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never use jQuery so cannot offer a potential solution with jQuery but with vanilla JS then perhaps something like this? The comments should illustrate what is happening at each stage of the js.

```js
// using a single delegated event listener
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement && e.target.dataset.cities != null ) {
    // toggle the button class
    e.target.classList.toggle('active');

    // find all the divs & buttons( active only! )
    let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.cities');
    let active = document.querySelectorAll('button.active');

    // ensure that all divs are hidden initially
    divs.forEach(n=>{
      if( !n.classList.contains('city') ) n.classList.add('city')
    })

    // iterate through active buttons to inspect their data-cities
    active.forEach(bttn=>{
      // create array of trimmed city names
      let cities = bttn.dataset.cities.split(',').map(n=>n.trim().toLowerCase());

      // if any div has an id that is within an active button data-cities, show it.
      divs.forEach(div=>{
        if( cities.includes( div.id.toLowerCase() ) ) div.classList.remove('city');
      });
    });

  }
})
```

```css
.city {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

div.cities,
button.city-button {
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<button class="city-button" type="button" data-cities="toronto, seattle">toronto, seattle</button>
<button class="city-button" type="button" data-cities="miami, seattle">miami, seattle</button>
<button class="city-button" type="button" data-cities="atlanta">atlanta</button>

<div id="toronto" class="cities city">toronto</div>
<div id="seattle" class="cities city">seattle</div>
<div id="miami" class="cities city">miami</div>
<div id="atlanta" class="cities city">atlanta</div>
```